# Is there a polymorphic 2D collection type that includes arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, interface, polymorphism

So let's say I have a helper class which contains methods that manipulate a collection:

```
public static void RemainingDegreeDistribution(IGraph graph, float[,] distArr)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < graph.Edges.Count; i++)
    {
        int startRemDeg = graph.Edges[i].Start.RemDeg;
        int endRemDeg = graph.Edges[i].End.RemDeg;
        distArr[startRemDeg,endRemDeg]++;
        distArr[endRemDeg, startRemDeg]++;
        total = total+2;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < distArr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < distArr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            distArr[i,j] /= total;
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I change the code to allow the collection that is passed in to either be an array or one of my own collection classes?**

The trouble is, the collection that is passed in must be 2-dimensional. There isn't an interface that I can implement in my own collection classes that arrays also implement.

I want to be able to reuse the code for both cases and avoid introducing lots of ugly conditional logic. I also need to avoid allocating memory so making some kind of wrapper class for arrays isn't acceptable. I also want to avoid using lists within lists as its so much simpler to work with normal 2d arrays and lists allocate too much memory for my purposes. It seems like this should be possible with indexers or something. Like is there a way to declare that "distArr" must be any type with an indexer that takes two arguments etc.?

Comment: KeyValuePair<string, object[,]>

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand how that is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such interface. So you need to make your own, for instance:

```
public interface IMatrix<T>
{
    int Rows { get; }
    int Columns { get; }
    ref T this[int row, int column] { get; }
}
```

and additionally of implementing it in your collection classes, create adapter for arrays ([Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)).

I know, I know, you said

> I also need to avoid allocating memory so making some kind of wrapper class for arrays isn't acceptable.

I don't think a tiny short lived GC3 generation wrapper object will hurt your system, but anyway, the heap allocation can be avoided by implementing the wrapper as a `struct`:

```
public struct ArrayMatrix<T> : IMatrix<T>
{
    readonly T[,] source;
    public ArrayMatrix(T[,] source) => this.source = source;
    public int Rows => source.GetLength(0);
    public int Columns => source.GetLength(1);
    public ref T this[int row, int column] => ref source[row, column];
}
```

and making your method *generic* (to avoid boxing of the `struct`):

```
public static void RemainingDegreeDistribution<TMatrix>(IGraph graph, TMatrix distArr)
    where TMatrix : IMatrix<float>
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.Edges.Count; i++)
    {
        int startRemDeg = graph.Edges[i].Start.RemDeg;
        int endRemDeg = graph.Edges[i].End.RemDeg;
        distArr[startRemDeg, endRemDeg]++;
        distArr[endRemDeg, startRemDeg]++;
        total = total + 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < distArr.Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < distArr.Columns; j++)
        {
            distArr[i, j] /= total;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it easier to be used with arrays, you could add a helper method:

```
public static class ArrayMatrix
{
    public static ArrayMatrix<T> ToMatrix<T>(this T[,] source) => new ArrayMatrix<T>(source);
}
```

and even provide overload of your method with array argument:

```
public static void RemainingDegreeDistribution(IGraph graph, float[,] distArr)
    => RemainingDegreeDistribution(graph, distArr.ToMatrix());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to represent point in 2D space i suggesto you to use Point data structure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.7.2

Try overloading if you also would pass an array of coordinates and points :

```
public static Method ( float[,] coordinates )
{
     //generate array of Points starting from coordinates , points.Add ( new Point(coordinate[i,j]) )
}

public static Method ( Point[] points)
{
     //actual logic
}
```